# Why isn't this ListItem click handler working?

Tags: android, android-listview, event-handling, listitem, mobile-development

I am developing an app comprising a ListView with items that can be clicked to get edited, but try as I might, coding the class ([AlarmsActivity](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/thengnet/medic/AlarmsActivity.java)) - ln 65 to ln 90 - that displays the list items to consume a click event, that will open up an activity, where it can be handled isn't functioning; it does work in the [adapter class](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blogspot/thengnet/medic/AlarmsAdapter.java) - ln 76 to ln 100 - that manages the list items, but such class is bereft of context and other elements I'll eventually need in development. How do I solve it?

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
binding.listviewAlarms.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> adapterView, View row, int position, long id) {
            /**
             * Dummy data to send to {@link EditAlarmActivity}
             * TODO: set up a database to contain the data, and use id to fetch data from it
             * instead of passing the data from this {@link AlarmsActivity}
             */
            mSelectedAlarmParamsList.addAll(Collections.singleton(alarms.toString()));
           // mSelectedScheduleParamsList.add(binding.listviewSchedules.getChildAt(position).toString()); // id of the selected CardView

            Alarm selectedAlarm = alarms.get(position);
            mSelectedAlarmParams.putStringArray("selected-alarm", new String[]{
                            selectedAlarm.getTitle(), selectedAlarm.getDescription(),
                            selectedAlarm.getStartDate(), selectedAlarm.getStartTime(),
                            selectedAlarm.getEndDate(), selectedAlarm.getEndTime()
                    }
            );
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "List item " + position + " clicked!!!");
            Snackbar.make(row, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "List item " + position + " clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(appContext, EditAlarmActivity.class).putExtras(mSelectedAlarmParams));
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the layout ID to the adapter constructor instead of 0.

```
alarmsAdapter = new AlarmsAdapter(this, 0, alarms);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm getting same behaviour -- used `R.layout.activity_alarms`
Should I figure out how to use `RecyclerView` or fixate on `ListView` first? I'm thinking it's best to solve the bug instead of jumping...

Comment: By default, ArrayAdapter creates a view for each array item by calling                                      
    `toString()` on each item and placing the contents in a TextView. You can provide 
           `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`                                                                                                 
            `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);`

Comment: To customize the appearance of each item you can override the `toString()` method for the objects in your array. Or, to create a view for each item that's something other than a `TextView` (for example, if you want an `ImageView` for each array item), extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and override `getView()` to return the type of view you want for each item. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews

Comment: I think you need `RecyclerView`, `ListAdapter` and `ViewHolder`

Comment: Right. I'm using a custom `ArrayAdapter`, and views are visible; you can see my overridden `getView()` in the `AlarmsAdapter` class, and click handler even works there. I need click handler to eork in `AlarmsActivity`, because it would be easier to handle events there.

Comment: You use `R.layout.alarm` in `getView()` (but I can't find it in res/layout). This layout (layout of `ListView` item) you should pass to instantiate of `ArrayAdapter`, I think this is the cause of your issue.

Comment: Seems I didn't push it; you can check it now -- [R.layout.alarm](https://github.com/Detective-Khalifah/MEDIC_--_Localised_Personal_Health_Tracker_Extended/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/alarm.xml)